# WiX - How do I copy existing files to a subdirectory before installed files of the same name overwrite them?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I have some file at `Program\file.json`, and I want my .msi to copy the file to `Program\Backup\file.json` before installing a new file at `Program\file.json` so that the old data is not lost.

I tried writing a `Program\backup.bat` which copies `Program\file.json` to `Program\Backup\file.json` and calling it with a CustomAction, but this does not work because I need to call the batch file *after* it is installed into the system's `Program` folder during InstallFiles so that it can move the old file.  However, InstallFiles is also when the new `Program\file.json` overwrites the old one.

I also tried doing it the WiX way by putting the following tag in another Component within the same Feature as the File tag responsible for the new `Program\file.json`:

`<CopyFile SourceDirectory="ProgramFolder" DestinationDirectory="BackupFolder" Id="Copy_of_File" SourceName="file.json"/>`

("ProgramFolder" is the Id of the Program Directory, and "BackupFolder" is the Id of the Program\Backup Directory)

However, this appears to copy the old version into `Program\Backup\file.json` but not overwrite it with the new version.  I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hacky solution and not one that scales well for big regularly-updating projects, but for my purposes it worked.

Using the `CopyFile` tag as above while also including `<Property Id='REINSTALLMODE' Value='a'/>` in the product will force it to reinstall all files, so the issue with it failing to overwrite the old file is averted.